# How to shorten these codes?

Tags: python, optimization

```
ts.groupby(ts.index.date).count().reindex(idx, fill_value = np.nan)
ts.groupby(ts.index.date).mean().reindex(idx, fill_value = np.nan)
ts.groupby(ts.index.date).sum().reindex(idx, fill_value = np.nan)
ts.groupby(ts.index.date).max().reindex(idx, fill_value = np.nan)
ts.groupby(ts.index.date).min().reindex(idx, fill_value = np.nan)
```

I'm looking for a more clever way to iterate many methods. If it was a string, the code can be written in a much more concise way

```
for i in ["count", "mean", "sum", "max", "min"]:
    "ts.groupby(ts.index.date).{}().reindex(idx, fill_value = np.nan)".format(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
for name in ("count", "mean", "sum", "max", "min"):
    func = getattr(ts.groupby(ts.index.date), name)
    func().reindex(idx, fill_value = np.nan)
```

Alternatives:

If and only if `ts.groupby(ts.index.date)` has the same result in all expressions, it can be evaluated only once.

```
tsg = ts.groupby(ts.index.date)
for name in ("count", "mean", "sum", "max", "min"):
    getattr(tsg, name)().reindex(idx, fill_value = np.nan)
```

And some find this easier to read:

```
for name in 'count mean sum max min'.split():
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for i in ["count", "mean", "sum", "max", "min"]:
    exec(f"ts.groupby(ts.index.date).{i}().reindex(idx, fill_value = np.nan)")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
[getattr(ts.groupby(ts.index.date), item)().reindex(idx, fill_value = np.nan) for item in ["count", "mean", "sum", "max", "min"]]
```

Comment: Thanks, it throws an error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'reindex'
`

Answer (score 0):

```
# The first line is to execute what you want
ts.groupby(ts.index.date).agg(['count','mean','std','min','max']).reset_index()

#The second line is to remove multilevel columns
ts.columns = list(map('_'.join, ts.columns.values))
```